# vscode activating virtual environment in home directory from a subdirectory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm connecting remotely to a server using ssh in vscode.

In my home directory, I have two "folders", `py3` which a virtual environment and `project1`.

When I connect to the home directory, I can activate `py3` without problems. But when I connect directly to the `project1` folder, I'm not able to see the `py3` in the list of virtual environments of vscode.

How can I activate it from a subfolder?

My question is not about the terminal, but how to do so from the vscode explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell VS Code where to look for virtual environments that are not in your workspace (hence why it can detect `py3`). You can either directly specify the environment via the `"python.pythonPath"` setting or put your home directory in the `"python.venvPath"` setting. Check out the [documentation on environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) for the details of where the extension looks for environments.