# Can I have multiple subfolders with virtual python environments in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-venv

I have a monorepo structured like this:

```
myRepo/
├─ project_1/
│  ├─ .venv/
│  ├─ main.py
├─ project_2/
│  ├─ .venv/
│  ├─ main.py
├─ .gitignore
├─ README.md
```

- Can VS Code handle multiple python venvs in subfolders?

After some googling I managed a find one solution, but its not very elegant. I created a workspace and added the folders `/project_1` and `/project_2`, that worked and I can easily switch and select Python Interpreter. I also need to modify files in `/root` from time to time so I added this folder as well. All this makes the Explorer folder structure bigger and more cluttered with duplicates of itself:

```
workspace/
├── myRepo/
│   ├── project_1/
│   │   ├── .venv/
│   │   └── main.py
│   ├── project_2/
│   │   ├── .venv/
│   │   └── main.py
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── README.md
│   └── myRepo/
├── project_1/
│   ├── .venv/
│   └── main.py
└── project_2/
    ├── .venv/
    └── main.py
```

Comment: What was the problem with the original file structure?

Comment: VS Code can't find the venvs it seems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148270/vscode-activating-virtual-environment-in-home-directory-from-a-subdirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code has a [list of places, where it looks for virtual environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments). Only environments located directly under the workspace are picked up automatically. You can also enter custom paths when running the `Python: Select Interpreter` command, though. Simply select "Enter interpreter path..." and navigate to your venv's `/bin/python` executable:

[image: select interpreter]

[image: enter interpreter path]

[image: find]

[image: python binary]

Once you have used a cutom interpreter path, it is known to VS code and will be directly selectable using the `Python: Select Interpreter` command.

Comment: If this works for you then there is definitely something wrong on my side. I've tried this several times, it just swaps back to the Interpreter I last used. Are you sure this works in a sub dir?

Comment: This works with any path in your workspace (and even out of your workspace). Did you press return on the "Find..." selection in the third screenshot? This should open a treeview in which you can navigate through your directories. Be sure to select the python binary, not the venv's path. I will update the answer with another screenshot.

Comment: Hmm, yes I used the Finder navigator didn't work - but it actually work when writing the path without the navigator like this `./project_1/.venv/bin/python` I'm on macOS btw. Looks like its a bit buggy. Thanks!

Comment: @NorwegianClassic Your comment helped me get the base interpreter running on macOS. But I have yet to find out how to get it to work with interactive Jupyter notebooks.